# Различие нативных и не нативных приложений для iOS

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin

Программа созданное на C# с использованием Xamarin для iOS будет работать также, как нативные приложении созданное с Swift? Быстрота работы и т.д

Comment: Все зависит исключительно от того, на чем Вы умеете лучше писать. Но в целом, по моему мнениею, Xamarin  не нужен. И вопросов не возникает.

Comment: Без Xamarin на iOS, думаю, невозможно писать приложении

Comment: думаю, Тим Кук с Вами не согласен:)

Comment: На С# без использования Xamarin невозможно писать для iOS

Comment: @KoVadim, а мне казалось xamarin выдает _нативное_ приложение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот тут](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/compiling_for_different_devices/) в документации объясняется, что для iOS используются два компилятора

> The regular Mono code generation engine and one based on the LLVM Optimizing Compiler

Один (Mono code generation engine) предлагается использовать для компиляции в процессе разработки, поскольку он быстрее компилирует. Второй (LLVM Optimizing Compiler) рекомендуется использовать для релизных билдов, поскольку в результате получается приложение, которое работает быстрее.

Поскольку используется LLVM компилятор (скорее всего немного отличающийся от того, который в xcode) то код, который получится, будет не сильно отличаться от того, что вы получите в xcode (это мое предположение).

Answer (score 0):

Приложение без нативный частей работают быстрей, т.к. не приходится перегонять с одного языка на другой. Программа работает на прямую с данными, а не через посредника. В добавок, Swift разработан специально для iOS, поэтому он более оптимизирован для этого.
Для разработки на iOS с помощью C# можно использовать Unity (больше подходит для игры) и есть другие кроссплатформенные среды для разработки.